# How to give a mob a custom AI?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I give a mob a custom AI by using commands? Like giving a giant the AI of a zombie, for example.

Comment: You can give a mob a custom AI, but it'll take a lot of commands and depends completely on what you want the mob to do. There's no single command or NBTag to change a mob's AI (other than switching it off with `NoAI`).

Answer (score 3):

As of 1.9, if a mob is riding another mob, the passenger will take over pathfinding of the host. The following summons a giant that has the pathfinding of a zombie.

```
/summon Giant ~ ~1 ~ {Passengers:[{id:"Zombie"}]}
```

However, this only affects pathfinding; the giant will still not attack, though you could use smoke and mirrors to accomplish that such as running a `/effect` command around the giant to target players.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, there is no NBT tag/data for it. See also https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#summon